# decorator enquiry in python

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm a self-taught programmer and needs your help on the @decorator in python.

Here is my question. After I run other(multiply) with decorator, it comes up with an error: wrap_func() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given. And I have no idea why and how to fix this. 
My main purpose is to learn how the decorator works; thus the following code might not make sense.

```
def multiply(a,b):
    return a*b
###pass in multiply function in other()

def other(multiply):
    print('passed in')
    print(multiply(1,2))

other(multiply)
### result shows passed in and 2, as expected

### Set up decorator func here
def decorator_prac(old_func):

    def wrap_func():
        multiply(1,2)
        old_func()
        print(1+7)
    return wrap_func

###add decorator on def other(multiply)
@decorator_prac
def other(multiply):
    print('what should I say')
    print(multiply(1,2))

###Run other(multiply)
other(multiply)
```

Output:

```
passed in
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 28, in <module>
    other(multiply)
TypeError: wrap_func() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
What you posted dies on a variety of indentation errors, with perhaps other problems lurking behind that.

Comment: I think I fixed the indentation ... I updated your posting, and I now have output compatible with your explanation and comments.  Please verify.

Comment: @Prune, thanks....didn't realize for indentation. My bad

Comment: @Prune, but how could I solve the error?

Answer (score 0):

You have a discrepancy between the function you pass and the way you use it.  Here's the trace and solution.  I double-checked the function as seen by the decorator, and then added the required argument.  If you need this to be generic, you'll need a generic argument list, such as `*args`.

```
### Set up decorator func here
def decorator_prac(old_func):
#def decorator_prac(old_func):
    print("decorator arg", old_func)    # Track what is passed in

    def wrap_func(func_arg):            # Accommodate the function profile
        multiply(1,2)
        old_func(func_arg)              # Implement the proper profile
        print(1+7)
    return wrap_func
```

Output:

```
passed in
2
decorator arg <function other at 0x7f0e7b21b378>
what should I say
2
8
```

Comment: but from my understanding, when I put multiply function as old_func, the function of old_func(func_arg) becomes multiply(func_org), I don't understand how could ever multiply(func_org) works?

Comment: You understand incorrectly: `func_arg` is `multiply`, such that `old_func(func_arg)`  becomes `other(multiply)`.  Then you call `multiply(1, 2)`, with the result you see.  I recommend that you insert more `print` commands, similar to the one I supplied, to track the flow of data through your code.

Answer (score 0):

The decorator takes a function object (here: `other(multiply)`) and returns another function `wrap_func()` which replaces it. The name `other` now refers to the replaced function.

While the original function takes a parameter, the replacement doesn't. Calling a parameterless function with an argument fails in the shown way.